# Sparse index does not improve sort in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, indexing, mongodb-query

I have a collection with >100k of documents.
A sample document will be like

```
{ 
    "created_at" : 1545039649, 
    "priority" : 3, 
    "id" : 68, 
    "name" : "document68"
}


db.mycol.find().sort({created_at:1})
```

and

```
db.mycol.find().sort({priority:1})
```

results in error.

```
Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Executor error during find command: OperationFailed: Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.",
    "code" : 96,
    "codeName" : "OperationFailed"
}
```

Then I indexed these fields.

```
db.mycol.createIndex({'priority':1})
db.mycol.createIndex({'created_at':1}, {sparse:true})
```

Added sparse index to **created_at** as it is a mandatory field.

Now

```
db.mycol.find().sort({priority:1})
```

gives the result. But

```
db.mycol.find().sort({created_at:1})
```

still results in the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sparse index can only be used when you filter by `created_at: {$exists: true}`.

The reason being that all the other records are not part of the index (but they are still supposed to appear in the result -- probably at the end).

Maybe you don't have to make the index sparse (which only makes sense when most of the records do not have the field -- otherwise you don't save much space in index storage anyway)? `created_at` sounds like most records would have it.

> Added sparse index to created_at as it is a mandatory field.

Actually, it is the other way around: You only want a sparse index when the field is optional (and quite rare).